# The method 'PermissionHandler' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading `PermissionHandler` to latest (5.0.0). The `PermissionHandler()` not found and also
`The name 'PermissionGroup' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`.

Here is a code snippet:

```
  PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted && permission != PermissionStatus.neverAskAgain) {
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
    if (permissions.containsValue(2))
      fileDownload(context, finalUrl);
  }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9):

That because from `permission_handler: ^5.0.0` the author [BaseFlow](https://github.com/Baseflow) made it more intuitive for us to use
as asked in [this issue ticker (#230)](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/230).

Your code snippet need to change like below:

```
  if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      fileDownload(context, finalUrl);
  }
```

So now those mapped like this:

```
old way                                                 new way
-------                                                 -------

await PermissionHandler()
   .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera)       await PermissionGroup.camera.status

await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
   [PermissionGroup.camera]))[PermissionGroup.camera]   await PermissionGroup.camera.request()

await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
   [PermissionGroup.camera, PermissionGroup.storage]))  await [PermissionGroup.camera,                                   PermissionGroup.storage].request()

await PermissionHandler().checkServiceStatus
   (PermissionGroup.location)                           await Permission.location.serviceStatus.isEnabled
```

Read more here: [this issue ticker (#230)](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/230).

Comment: the author did very noticeable changes

Answer (score 6):

Use permission_handler: ^3.0.0 ,it Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Those who are still struggling with this, please follow the instructions

The latest version for handling permissions is now

> permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.8

Now I think they have changed the usage.

Use case: I have to give check contact permissions in order to save a contact in the phone directory. SO This works perfectly for me.

```
  Future<void> saveContactInPhone() async {
    try {

      print("saving Conatct");
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await Permission.contacts.request();
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      Contact newContact = new Contact();

        newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
        newContact.familyName ="abc";

          newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);

      } else {
        //_handleInvalidPermissions(context);
      }
    } else {
      Contact newContact = new Contact();

        newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
        newContact.familyName ="abc";

          newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
    }
      print("object");      

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Please refer [Permission_handler_example](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-example-tab-) for more info

Answer (score 1):

**Please adhere to following config**

pubspec.yaml

```
permission_handler: ^6.1.1
```

import

```
   import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

check permissions like

```
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {

  String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).absolute.path + "/documents";

}
```